# Unusual Console.Write behaviour

Tags: c#, console

Console.Write isn't behaving as it should; I'm trying to create a class that handles drawing to specific regions of the console, and some really odd stuff's been happening. I've got no clue how to debug it.

When I throw this code in:

```
string output;

for (int i = 0; i < Console.WindowHeight; ++i) {
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
    output = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < Console.WindowWidth; ++j) output += (i % 10).ToString();
    Console.Write(output);
}
```

I get the following: http://snag.gy/LrFcU.jpg (I'm not allowed to post images because of reputation limits -.-)

Yet when I modify it like so:

```
string output;

for (int i = 0; i < Console.WindowHeight; ++i) {
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
    output = "";

    // take one character away from the string
    for (int j = 0; j < Console.WindowWidth - 1; ++j) output += (i % 10).ToString();

    Console.Write(output);
}
```

I get this! http://snag.gy/jxLH8.jpg

WindowWidth is 80, WindowHeight is 25, and both buffer width and height are equal to window width and window height.

I'm resetting the cursor position every interation of the outer for loop... Why would it be omitting the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line isn't omitted, it's just that it scrolled out of sight.

You're adding one more character in the first version, thus reaching the end of the line and putting the caret on the next line.

Comment: The caret's being reset each line though, why would filling the line force the line upwards?

Comment: @Archmage `Console.Write` writes a character at the current position **and** move the caret. Otherwise all your characters would be written at the same position.

Comment: I understand this, what I don't understand is how that has any bearing on how the characters are **displayed**. Or... is it because the final line's caret position is on a new line, and that pushes the first one off? And if that's the case, how would I handle writing to the console to fill that character space **without** pushing the top line off?

Comment: A friend I showed this to mentioned that this is indeed the case... and adding Console.BufferWidth++ before and Console.BufferWidth-- after got it working as expected!